Selenium is not fill email line/Python. Message: Move target (-34, -417) is out of bounds of viewport dimensions (1908, 989)
Why i have this trouble?
Message: Move target (-34, -417) is out of bounds of viewport dimensions (1908, 989)
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:193:5
MoveTargetOutOfBoundsError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:479:5
assertInViewPort@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Actions.sys.mjs:2363:11
dispatch@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Actions.sys.mjs:1144:21
dispatch/pendingEvents<@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Actions.sys.mjs:2019:14
dispatch@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Actions.sys.mjs:2018:39

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

link = 'https://account.proton.me/mail/signup?plan=free&ref=mail_plus_intro-mailpricing-2&currency=EUR'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

ActionChains(browser)
data = {
    'birthdayMonth'
}
try:
    browser.get(url=link)
    time.sleep(10)
    email_input=browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="password"]')
    

    ActionChains(browser)\
        .move_by_offset(10, 10)\
        .move_to_element(email_input).click().send_keys("abc").perform()


    time.sleep(10)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()```


You have this issue in cases when your input is not in viewport (page is not completely rendered)
To avoid the issue you should wait for element to be visible, using expected_conditions.
Please, note that email element is placed in iframe and it's input is not interactable by keyboard, so to fill in email you should switch to frame context first, wait for input to be visible, click on it and then perform send_keys from ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

link = 'https://account.proton.me/mail/signup?plan=free&ref=mail_plus_intro-mailpricing-2&currency=EUR'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
browser.get(link)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[src*=username]')))
email_input = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email')))
email_input.click()
actions.send_keys('test@test.test').perform()
browser.switch_to.default_content()

password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
password.send_keys('test')

